# Windows 10 MUI language issue Notepad, Wordpad and Paint are in the wrong language

Tags: windows, windows-10, language

Some of my windows default apps are in the wrong language after updating from 1809 to 21h1 LTSC. This only includes Wordpad, Notepad and Paint. I have a Chinese installation of the Windows 10 system, however I do need the language to set to English

I have found this may be something related to the [system MUI language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/user-interface-language-management)

[image: Notepad language]

[image: Paint language]

Oddly enough the window prompt in the notepad has the correct language
[[image: prompt Language is correct][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX8Uu.png)

Comment: I also found this maybe to related to this as well
https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/jbkpa6/notepad_is_in_the_wrong_language_after_installed/